# How can I change the current player animation when "jump" is pressed

Tags: java, animation, 2d

I'm currently using the book "Developing games in Java" by David Brackeen to build a 2D platforming game as a project. The animations for each sprite are done in such a way that make them constant while the program is running, but I want to be able to change the animation when the player presses jump as well as freeze the animation or add another animation for when the player is standing still. I am by no means an experienced programmer, so I apologize for the horrible code but hopefully it's somewhat readable.

This is the class containing the main method

```
package tilegame;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import graphics.*;
import sound.*;
import input.*;
import core.GameCore;
import tilegame.sprites.*;
import tilegame.ResourceManager;


/**
GameManager manages all parts of the game.
*/
public class GameManager extends GameCore {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GameManager().run();  


 }

private static final AudioFormat PLAYBACK_FORMAT =
        new AudioFormat(44100, 16, 1, true, false);

public static final float GRAVITY = 0.002f;

private Point pointCache = new Point();
private TileMap map;
private SoundManager soundManager;
private ResourceManager resourceManager;
private InputManager inputManager;
private TileMapRenderer renderer;
private Sound jumpSound;

private GameAction moveLeft;
private GameAction moveRight;
private GameAction jump;
private GameAction exit;



public void init() {
    super.init();

    // set up input manager
    initInput();    

    // start resource manager
    resourceManager = new ResourceManager(
    screen.getFullScreenWindow().getGraphicsConfiguration());

    // load resources
    renderer = new TileMapRenderer();
    renderer.setBackground(
    resourceManager.loadImage("background.png"));

    // load first map
    map = resourceManager.loadNextMap();

    // load sounds
    soundManager = new SoundManager(PLAYBACK_FORMAT);
    jumpSound = soundManager.getSound("sounds/jump.wav");

    String fileName = "sounds/music.wav";
    playLoop(fileName);

    }  

public void stop() {
    super.stop();
    soundManager.close();
 }


private void initInput() {

    moveLeft = new GameAction("moveLeft");
    moveRight = new GameAction("moveRight");
    jump = new GameAction("jump",
        GameAction.DETECT_INITAL_PRESS_ONLY);
    exit = new GameAction("exit",
        GameAction.DETECT_INITAL_PRESS_ONLY);

    inputManager = new InputManager(
        screen.getFullScreenWindow());
    inputManager.setCursor(InputManager.INVISIBLE_CURSOR);

    inputManager.mapToKey(moveLeft, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
    inputManager.mapToKey(moveRight, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    inputManager.mapToKey(jump, KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
    inputManager.mapToKey(exit, KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);

}

// checks the users input for player movement 
private void checkInput(long elapsedTime) {

    if (exit.isPressed()) {
        stop();
    }

    Player player = (Player)map.getPlayer();
    if (player.isAlive()) {
        float velocityX = 0;
        if (moveLeft.isPressed()) {
            velocityX-=player.getMaxSpeed();
        }
        if (moveRight.isPressed()) {
            velocityX+=player.getMaxSpeed();
        }
        if (jump.isPressed()) {
            player.jump(false);
            soundManager.play(jumpSound);
        }
        player.setVelocityX(velocityX);
    }
  }

// plays an instance of a chosen sound
public void playSound(String soundName){

      try {   

       AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(soundName).getAbsoluteFile( ));
       Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip( );
       clip.open(audioInputStream);
       clip.start( );  

      }     
      catch(Exception ex)      
      {       
        System.out.println("Error");
        ex.printStackTrace( );        
    }       
 }


// loops an instance of a chosen sound
public void playLoop(String soundName){

    try {   

     AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(soundName).getAbsoluteFile( ));
     Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip( );
     clip.open(audioInputStream);
     clip.start( );  
     clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);

    }     
    catch(Exception ex)      
    {     
      System.out.println("Error");
      ex.printStackTrace( );        
  }   

  }

public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
    renderer.draw(g, map,
        screen.getWidth(), screen.getHeight());

}

public TileMap getMap() {
    return map;
}

public Point getTileCollision(Sprite sprite,
    float newX, float newY)
{
    float fromX = Math.min(sprite.getX(), newX);
    float fromY = Math.min(sprite.getY(), newY);
    float toX = Math.max(sprite.getX(), newX);
    float toY = Math.max(sprite.getY(), newY);

    // get the tile locations
    int fromTileX = TileMapRenderer.pixelsToTiles(fromX);
    int fromTileY = TileMapRenderer.pixelsToTiles(fromY);
    int toTileX = TileMapRenderer.pixelsToTiles(
        toX + sprite.getWidth() - 1);
    int toTileY = TileMapRenderer.pixelsToTiles(
        toY + sprite.getHeight() - 1);

    // check each tile for a collision
    for (int x=fromTileX; x<=toTileX; x++) {
        for (int y=fromTileY; y<=toTileY; y++) {
            if (x < 0 || x >= map.getWidth() ||
                map.getTile(x, y) != null)
            {
                // collision found, return the tile
                pointCache.setLocation(x, y);
                return pointCache;
            }
        }
    }

    // no collision found
    return null;
  }

public boolean isCollision(Sprite s1, Sprite s2) {
    // if the Sprites are the same, return false
    if (s1 == s2) {
        return false;
    }

    // if one of the Sprites is a dead Creature, return false
    if (s1 instanceof Creature && !((Creature)s1).isAlive()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (s2 instanceof Creature && !((Creature)s2).isAlive()) {
        return false;
    }

    // get the pixel location of the Sprites
    int s1x = Math.round(s1.getX());
    int s1y = Math.round(s1.getY());
    int s2x = Math.round(s2.getX());
    int s2y = Math.round(s2.getY());

    // check if the two sprites' boundaries intersect
    return (s1x < s2x + s2.getWidth() &&
        s2x < s1x + s1.getWidth() &&
        s1y < s2y + s2.getHeight() &&
        s2y < s1y + s1.getHeight());
}

public Sprite getSpriteCollision(Sprite sprite) {

    // run through the list of Sprites
    Iterator i = map.getSprites();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Sprite otherSprite = (Sprite)i.next();
        if (isCollision(sprite, otherSprite)) {
            // collision found, return the Sprite
            return otherSprite;
        }
    }

    // no collision found
    return null;
}

public void update(long elapsedTime) {
    Creature player = (Creature)map.getPlayer();


    // player is dead! start map over
    if (player.getState() == Creature.STATE_DEAD) {
        map = resourceManager.reloadMap();
        return;
    }              

    // get keyboard/mouse input
    checkInput(elapsedTime);

    // update player
    updateCreature(player, elapsedTime);
    player.update(elapsedTime);

    // update other sprites
    Iterator i = map.getSprites();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Sprite sprite = (Sprite)i.next();
        if (sprite instanceof Creature) {
            Creature creature = (Creature)sprite;
            if (creature.getState() == Creature.STATE_DEAD) {
                i.remove();
            }
            else {
                updateCreature(creature, elapsedTime);
            }
        }
        // normal update
        sprite.update(elapsedTime);
    }
   }

private void updateCreature(Creature creature,
    long elapsedTime)
{

    // apply gravity
    if (!creature.isFlying()) {
        creature.setVelocityY(creature.getVelocityY() +
            GRAVITY * elapsedTime);
    }

    // change x
    float dx = creature.getVelocityX();
    float oldX = creature.getX();
    float newX = oldX + dx * elapsedTime;
    Point tile =
        getTileCollision(creature, newX, creature.getY());
    if (tile == null) {
        creature.setX(newX);
    }
    else {
        // line up with the tile boundary
        if (dx > 0) {
            creature.setX(
                TileMapRenderer.tilesToPixels(tile.x) -
                creature.getWidth());
        }
        else if (dx < 0) {
            creature.setX(
                TileMapRenderer.tilesToPixels(tile.x + 1));
        }
        creature.collideHorizontal();
    }
    if (creature instanceof Player) {
        checkPlayerCollision((Player)creature, false);
      }

    // change y
    float dy = creature.getVelocityY();
    float oldY = creature.getY();
    float newY = oldY + dy * elapsedTime;
    tile = getTileCollision(creature, creature.getX(), newY);
    if (tile == null) {
        creature.setY(newY);
    }
    else {
        // line up with the tile boundary
        if (dy > 0) {
            creature.setY(
                TileMapRenderer.tilesToPixels(tile.y) -
                creature.getHeight());
        }
        else if (dy < 0) {
            creature.setY(
                TileMapRenderer.tilesToPixels(tile.y + 1));
        }
        creature.collideVertical();
    }
    if (creature instanceof Player) {
        boolean canKill = (oldY < creature.getY());
        checkPlayerCollision((Player)creature, canKill);
    }

}

public void checkPlayerCollision(Player player,
    boolean canKill)
{
    if (!player.isAlive()) {
        return;
    }

    // check for player collision with other sprites
    Sprite collisionSprite = getSpriteCollision(player);
    if (collisionSprite instanceof Items) {
        acquirePowerUp((Items)collisionSprite);
    }
    else if (collisionSprite instanceof Creature) {
        Creature badguy = (Creature)collisionSprite;
        if (canKill) {
            // kill the badguy and make player bounce
            String fileName = "sounds/impact.wav";
            playSound(fileName);
            badguy.setState(Creature.STATE_DYING);
            player.setY(badguy.getY() - player.getHeight());
            player.jump(true);
        }
        else {
            // player dies!
            String fileName = "sounds/death.wav";
            playSound(fileName);
            player.setState(Creature.STATE_DYING);
        }
    }
}

public void acquirePowerUp(Items powerUp) {
    // remove it from the map
    map.removeSprite(powerUp);

    if (powerUp instanceof Items.Coin) {
        // do something here, like give the player points
        String fileName = "sounds/coin.wav";
        playSound(fileName);

    }
    else if (powerUp instanceof Items.Door) {
        // advance to next map
        String fileName = "sounds/door.wav";
        playSound(fileName);
        map = resourceManager.loadNextMap();
    }
   }

  }
```

and this is the class that creates the animation for the player.

```
package tilegame;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import graphics.*;
import tilegame.sprites.*;


/**
The ResourceManager class loads and manages tile Images and
 Sprites used in the game. Game Sprites are cloned from
 the original Sprites.
*/
public class ResourceManager{

private ArrayList tiles;
private int currentMap;
private GraphicsConfiguration gc;

// Sprites used for cloning
private Sprite playerSprite;
private Sprite playerJump;
private Sprite coinSprite;
private Sprite doorSprite;
private Sprite grubSprite;
private Sprite batSprite;
private Sprite houndSprite;





public ResourceManager(GraphicsConfiguration gc) {
    this.gc = gc;
    loadTileImages();
    loadCreatureSprites();
    loadItemSprites();


}


public Image loadImage(String name) {
    String filename = "images/" + name;
    return new ImageIcon(filename).getImage();
}


public Image getMirrorImage(Image image) {
    return getScaledImage(image, -1, 1);
}

public Image getFlippedImage(Image image) {
    return getScaledImage(image, 1, -1);
}


private Image getScaledImage(Image image, float x, float y) {

    // set up the transform
    AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
    transform.scale(x, y);
    transform.translate(
        (x-1) * image.getWidth(null) / 2,
        (y-1) * image.getHeight(null) / 2);

    // create a transparent (not translucent) image
    Image newImage = gc.createCompatibleImage(
        image.getWidth(null),
        image.getHeight(null),
        Transparency.BITMASK);

    // draw the transformed image
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)newImage.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, transform, null);
    g.dispose();

    return newImage;
}


public TileMap loadNextMap(){
    TileMap map = null;
    while (map == null) {
        currentMap++;

        try {
            map = loadMap(
                "maps/map" + currentMap + ".txt");

                Thread.sleep(200);                
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();            

        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            if (currentMap == 1) {
                // no maps to load!
                return null;
            }

            currentMap = 0;
            map = null;
        }
    }


    return map;
}


public TileMap reloadMap() {
    try {
        return loadMap(
            "maps/map" + currentMap + ".txt");
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}


private TileMap loadMap(String filename)
    throws IOException
{
    ArrayList lines = new ArrayList();
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    // read every line in the text file into the list
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new FileReader(filename));
    while (true) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        // no more lines to read
        if (line == null) {
            reader.close();
            break;
        }

        // add every line except for comments
        if (!line.startsWith("#")) {
            lines.add(line);
            width = Math.max(width, line.length());
        }
    }

    // parse the lines to create a TileEngine
    height = lines.size();
    TileMap newMap = new TileMap(width, height);
    for (int y=0; y<height; y++) {
        String line = (String)lines.get(y);
        for (int x=0; x<line.length(); x++) {
            char ch = line.charAt(x);

            // check if the char represents tile A, B, C etc.
            int tile = ch - 'A';
            if (tile >= 0 && tile < tiles.size()) {
                newMap.setTile(x, y, (Image)tiles.get(tile));
            }

            // check if the char represents a sprite
            else if (ch == 'o') {
                addSprite(newMap, coinSprite, x, y);
            }
            else if (ch == '*') {
                addSprite(newMap, doorSprite, x, y);
            }
            else if (ch == '1') {
                addSprite(newMap, grubSprite, x, y);
            }
            else if (ch == '2') {
                addSprite(newMap, batSprite, x, y);
            }
            else if (ch == '3') {
                addSprite(newMap, houndSprite, x, y);
            }
        }
    }


    // add the player to the map
    Sprite player = (Sprite)playerSprite.clone();
    player.setX(TileMapRenderer.tilesToPixels(2));
    player.setY(0);
    newMap.setPlayer(player);

    return newMap;
}


private void addSprite(TileMap map,
    Sprite hostSprite, int tileX, int tileY)
{
    if (hostSprite != null) {
        // clone the sprite from the "host"
        Sprite sprite = (Sprite)hostSprite.clone();

        // center the sprite
        sprite.setX(
            TileMapRenderer.tilesToPixels(tileX) +
            (TileMapRenderer.tilesToPixels(1) -
            sprite.getWidth()) / 2);

        // bottom-justify the sprite
        sprite.setY(
            TileMapRenderer.tilesToPixels(tileY + 1) -
            sprite.getHeight());

        // add it to the map
        map.addSprite(sprite);
    }
}


// -----------------------------------------------------------
// code for loading sprites and images
// -----------------------------------------------------------


public void loadTileImages() {
    // keep looking for tile A,B,C, etc. this makes it
    // easy to drop new tiles in the images/ directory
    tiles = new ArrayList();
    char ch = 'A';
    while (true) {
        String name = "tile_" + ch + ".png";
        File file = new File("images/" + name);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            break;
        }
        tiles.add(loadImage(name));
        ch++;
    }
}



public void loadCreatureSprites() {

    Image[][] images = new Image[8][];

    // load left-facing images
    images[0] = new Image[] {
        loadImage("player1.png"),
        loadImage("player2.png"),
        loadImage("player3.png"),
        loadImage("player4.png"),
        loadImage("player5.png"),
        loadImage("player6.png"),
        loadImage("player7.png"),
        loadImage("player8.png"),
        loadImage("bat1.png"),
        loadImage("bat2.png"),
        loadImage("bat3.png"),
        loadImage("bat4.png"),
        loadImage("grub1.png"),
        loadImage("grub2.png"),
        loadImage("hound1.png"),
        loadImage("hound2.png"),
        loadImage("hound3.png"),
        loadImage("hound4.png"),
        loadImage("hound5.png"),
        loadImage("jump1.png"),
        loadImage("jump2.png"),
        loadImage("jump3.png")

    };

    images[1] = new Image[images[0].length];
    images[2] = new Image[images[0].length];
    images[3] = new Image[images[0].length];

    for (int i=0; i<images[0].length; i++) {
        // right-facing images
        images[1][i] = getMirrorImage(images[0][i]);
        // left-facing "dead" images
        images[2][i] = getFlippedImage(images[0][i]);
        // right-facing "dead" images
        images[3][i] = getFlippedImage(images[1][i]);

    }

    // create creature animations
    Animation[] playerAnim = new Animation[4];
    Animation[] batAnim = new Animation[4];
    Animation[] grubAnim = new Animation[4];
    Animation[] houndAnim = new Animation[4];
    Animation[] playerJumpAnim = new Animation[4];

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {

        playerAnim[i] = createPlayerAnim(
            images[i][0], images[i][1], images[i][2],
            images[i][3], images[i][4], images[i][5],
            images[i][6], images[i][7]);

        batAnim[i] = createBatAnim(
            images[i][8], images[i][9], images[i][10], images[i][11]);

        grubAnim[i] = createGrubAnim(
            images[i][12], images[i][13]);

        houndAnim[i] = createHoundAnim(
                images[i][14], images[i][15], images[i][16], 
                images[i][17], images [i][18]);

        playerJumpAnim[i] = createJumpAnim(
                images[i][19], images[i][20], images[i][21]);


    }


    // changing player sprite for different movements notes.
    // possible solutions: 
    // add keylistener 

    playerSprite = new Player(playerAnim[0], playerAnim[1],
                        playerAnim[2], playerAnim[3]);

    playerJump = new Player(playerJumpAnim[0], playerJumpAnim[1],
            playerJumpAnim[2], playerJumpAnim[3]);   

    batSprite = new Bat(batAnim[0], batAnim[1],
        batAnim[2], batAnim[3]);

    grubSprite = new Grub(grubAnim[0], grubAnim[1],
        grubAnim[2], grubAnim[3]);

    houndSprite = new Hound(houndAnim[0], houndAnim[1],
            houndAnim[2], houndAnim[3]);

} 

private Animation createPlayerAnim(Image img1, Image img2, 
    Image img3, Image img4, 
    Image img5, Image img6, 
    Image img7, Image img8)
{
    Animation anim = new Animation();             
    anim.addFrame(img1, 100);  
    anim.addFrame(img2, 100); 
    anim.addFrame(img3, 100);
    anim.addFrame(img4, 100);  
    anim.addFrame(img5, 100); 
    anim.addFrame(img6, 100);
    anim.addFrame(img7, 100);     
    anim.addFrame(img8, 100);
    return anim;

}

private Animation createJumpAnim(Image img1, Image img2, 
        Image img3)
    {
        Animation anim = new Animation();             
        anim.addFrame(img1, 100);  
        anim.addFrame(img2, 100); 
        anim.addFrame(img3, 100);          
        return anim;

    }

private Animation createBatAnim(Image img1, Image img2,
    Image img3, Image img4)
{
    Animation anim = new Animation();
    anim.addFrame(img1, 100);
    anim.addFrame(img2, 100);
    anim.addFrame(img3, 100);
    anim.addFrame(img4, 125);                     
    return anim;
}

private Animation createGrubAnim(Image img1, Image img2) {
    Animation anim = new Animation();
    anim.addFrame(img1, 250);
    anim.addFrame(img2, 250);
    return anim;
}

private Animation createHoundAnim(Image img1, Image img2, 
        Image img3, Image img4, Image img5) {

    Animation anim = new Animation();
    anim.addFrame(img1, 200);
    anim.addFrame(img2, 150);
    anim.addFrame(img3, 200);
    anim.addFrame(img4, 150);
    anim.addFrame(img5, 150);    
    return anim;
}

private void loadItemSprites() {
    // create "door" sprite
    Animation anim = new Animation();
    anim.addFrame(loadImage("door1.png"), 300);
    anim.addFrame(loadImage("door2.png"), 250);
    anim.addFrame(loadImage("door3.png"), 300);
    anim.addFrame(loadImage("door4.png"), 475);
    anim.addFrame(loadImage("door3.png"), 300);
    anim.addFrame(loadImage("door2.png"), 200);
    anim.addFrame(loadImage("door1.png"), 800);
    doorSprite = new Items.Door(anim);

    // create "coin" sprite
    anim = new Animation();
    anim.addFrame(loadImage("coin1.png"), 150);
    anim.addFrame(loadImage("coin2.png"), 150);
    anim.addFrame(loadImage("coin3.png"), 150);
    anim.addFrame(loadImage("coin4.png"), 150);
    anim.addFrame(loadImage("coin5.png"), 150);
    anim.addFrame(loadImage("coin6.png"), 150);
    coinSprite = new Items.Coin(anim);

}


}
```

what I want is to use the method below here to change the players current animation when "jump" is pressed, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it working. There are other classes included in the project that might need to be seen to figure this out. I didn't want to post too much code but it seems a little late for that now.

```
   private Animation createJumpAnim(Image img1, Image img2, 
       Image img3)
    {
      Animation anim = new Animation();             
      anim.addFrame(img1, 100);  
      anim.addFrame(img2, 100); 
      anim.addFrame(img3, 100);          
      return anim;

  }
```